# Countably infinite Hamel bases

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,\ldots\}$ and $\{w_1,w_2,w_3,\ldots\}$ be two countably infinite Hamel bases of the same vector space.  Must there be infinitely many values of $n$ for which $\operatorname{span}\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ $= \operatorname{span}\{w_1,\ldots,w_n\}$?

**Later note:** Shortly after posting this I wondered why I would think such a thing, and thought of deleting the question.  Then it occurred to me that maybe this is true with a simple additional hypothesis, but I'm not sure what it is.  Maybe more later?

Comment: Now I'm trying to remember what made me think this might be the case......

Comment: It should be easy to find two Hamel bases such that no two finite subsets have the same span actually.

Comment: A vague intuition: I omitted some simple hypothesis with which we would get this conclusion.  Now I need to figure out what it might have been.  This wild guess seems silly three hours after I posted it.

Comment: Did you remember the extra hypothesis?

Answer (score 4):

No. For instance, take a Hamel Basis $(e_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ and define $(v_n)$ in such a way that $v_1,\dots,v_n$ is mostly even $e_{2k}$ and an occasional uneven $e_{2k+1}$ (for instance you only add an uneven term once you hit $n=2^p$), and the opposite for $w_n$. If you chose things right, there'll be no number $n$ such that the spans coincide.